# How to know all divs within an area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to click and get all divs within a radius of the click.

The ammount of divs can easily be 200+, so cycling through all and checking their distance to the mouse doesn't seem very efficient.

I thought something like dividing my parent div both width and height by 10, and having the divs class be different depending on their "quadrant", so upon creation, the div will have the proper class to identify what quadrant it is in.

Example, parent element width is 1100px, and height 700px. Each quadrant would be 110px by 70px

If a mouse click was at x: 560px and y: 450px then its quadrant would be x:5 and y:6.

And from there I could do something like

```
if ((quadrantX == 5) & (quadrantY == 6)) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("quadrant123");
}
```

But making 100 "ifs" doesn't seem very efficient either, I'm not sure how to go on from there or if this is the right thread to pull

Comment: If you can create an object of div elements with their element, x1, y1, x2, y2, then upon mouse click you can traverse through their coordinates if they are inclining with the clicked position + radius. The x1, x2, y1, y2 should be offset from documents 0, 0.

Comment: Iterating through all of them and calculating the distance using point slope, really shouldn't be that slow, and it would likely be easier than keeping track of the divs quadrants

Comment: When the document loads the object should be created. not every time. Iterating all of them is not a problem if you can make an arrangement of divs in special order. ex: { '100:200': [ { elem: obj, x1: 100, y1:200, x2: 150, y2: 250}, {}, {}], '151:200': [{div}, {div}]} . something like this type of object where you can easily findout.(Not exactly like this)